# Nested JSON PARSING in Python. Get a value of an object using value of another

Tags: python, json, json.net

I have a json file that is heavily nested.

I am trying to get the Value of key ‘value’ by key ‘uniqueid’ in python.

I have a separate file where i have a list of the unique id and what it means.

I want to do something like a find function where I give the uniqueid and it returns the value of key ‘value’ from the json. Eg. I need to find korea using uniqueid 123456789.

The keys in the json are not unique.And the json file is big with similar pattern.

```
  "Items" : [ {
        "type" : "group1",
        "columns" : [ {
          "fields" : [ {
            "type" : "country",
            "UniqueID" : "123456789",
            "value" : "korea",         
          }, {
            "type" : "country",
            "UniqueID" : "987782999",
            "value" : “Japan",
          } ]
        } ]
```

Input will be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At the end you just need to go  to the fields list and iterate it looking for an specific id

```
for i in myDict["Items"][0]["columns"][0]["fields"]: 
    if i["UniqueID"] == "123456789": 
        print(i["value"])
```